# I’d like to go to Canada someday

Tags: riddle

A very easy riddle for you:

> It is me, the silent killer
>
> Many siblings, some very familiar
>
> Some teach you music of Strauss and Liszt
>
> Some want you to *Bon Appetit*
>
> Some are white and emit light
>
> And some are white and very sick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that the riddle is not as easy as I might think...

The answer is:

> Rat/mouse

```
It is me, the silent killer
```

> Referencing the Bubonic Plague/Black Death. While many people in Europe at the time believed in a "silent" killer that moved through the air, the real culprit was rat that transmit the plague.

```
Many siblings, some very familiar
```

> The many popular images of mouses and rats in movies and culture.

```
Some teach you music of Strauss and Liszt
```

> Referencing the music used in the popular cartoon Tom & Jerry, particularly [Johann Mouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Mouse) and [The Cat Concerto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cat_Concerto).

```
Some want you to Bon Appetit
```

> Referencing the movie [Ratatouille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratatouille_(film)), a movie about a French rat with the desire to become a chef.

```
Some are white and emit light
```

> Computer mouse! Early computer mouses are white in color, and today Apple still design is mouse with an uniform [white color](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=beL&channel=fs&biw=1301&bih=609&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=Spq6W6ysKOvIjwTczrLQAg&q=apple%20computer%20mouse&oq=apple%20computer%20mouse&gs_l=img.3.6.0j0i5i30j0i8i30j0i24j0i10i24j0i24l5.2337.2963..3155...0.0..0.80.329.5......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i7i30j0i7i5i30j0i8i7i30.TwtRHLlscNw#imgrc=_).

```
And some are white and very sick!
```

> Laboratory mouses are predominantly albino for fewer genetic variability. They are tested with all kinds of sickness to model treatment in human.

And title:

> There are no rats in [Alberta, Canada](http://www1.agric.gov.ab.ca/$department/deptdocs.nsf/All/agdex3441) due to an aggressive control effort.

Answer (score 5):

Is this

> Teeth?

It is me, the silent killer

> Either because you can chew food silently "killing" them, or you kill silence by speaking?

Many siblings, some very familiar

> Teeth come in pairs, so the matching ones are familiar to one another?

Some teach you music of Strauss and Liszt

> Our mouths/teeth let us sing

Some want you to Bon Appetit

> And eat, of course.

Some are white and emit light

> Some teeth are so white they gleam.

And some are white and very sick!

> Teeth can be weakened by bleaching? By googling there's apparently something called Hypomineralization, which leaves white deposits on teeth as well.

I could be so off the mark with my answer, but I was tempted to try since you said this was easy and no one has tried :)

Comment: I like this answer, but I wonder what this has to do with the title.

Comment: Same here, Joe!

Answer (score 2):

Wild guess,

> Snow?

It is me, the silent killer

> It is usually quitet when it snows, and it can hurt people.

Many siblings, some very familiar

> Rain sleet snow or hail.

Some teach you music of Strauss and Liszt

> ?

Some want you to Bon Appetit

> Don't eat the yellow snow.

Some are white and emit light

> Snow is white?

And some are white and very sick!

> People can be pale and get sick in the cold.

Comment: (ROT13) Jurer V yvir, gurer vf ab fabj, fb vf vg bxnl vs lbh pbhyq rkcynva ubj vg jbhyq uheg crbcyr? Zl bayl thrff vf na ninynapur, ohg gung vf abg fvyrag, be ng yrnfg abg va zbivrf. $\ast$ But apart from that, your answer seems fine, and I see how it relates to the title. $(+1)$ :P

Comment: @user477343 think the hurt is meant as rot13(qlvat bs gur pbyq, crbcyr gura trg irel gverq snyy nfyrrc naq qvr ol gur fabj, juvpu vf n fvyrag qrngu) also (+1) fits nice to the title

Comment: @mrdeadseven ahh, thanks for the clarification. I also saw the edit of this answer :P